# Don't change the size of subview with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

so what I have done is I created a small view and then I have an image view as a subview to the small view. I've created an animation so that while the photo is loading for example the background view would scale. The animation aspect works correctly and how I want it to; however the image view also does it and resizes based on the small view which is not what I want, I just want the image view to stay where it is and not grow or do anything. My only constraints for the image view are its height and width as well as center x and y. I have not put any code to stop this, but I just know it's probably and autoresizing or auto layout or something. 
Thank you so much in advance!

How it is right now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv13xh88vlt89f3/growingView.mov?dl=0

How it should be: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cq4ej2uo4n7fxj/howItShouldBe.mov?dl=0

Pictures of my constraints:

the subview:[image]

the view: [image]

I hope those videos help. Basically I just want the image view to not move anywhere stay where it is, and have the background view scale

Comment: It's missing some code. What are the constraints really on width and height of the subview?

Comment: both views are 130x130

Comment: what code am I missing? The only code I have done is the animation, nothing with the subview

Comment: Then some screenshot of your constraints. That's not part of "code" as we use to say it, but it still part of your doing and is just an interface user friendly for code.

Comment: I just added the constraints

Comment: you added Animation to **self.ImageView.layer** which make your imageView to grow as per animation written and I think you just need to vary **self.imageView.layer.borderWidth** so, Image remains of Same Height or width just border gets its width pr height increased